# Can't query stored procedure with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to submit CLOB

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, clob

I fire a SQL statement to start a procedure with only one input Parameter, a clob. But it doesn't work, and I don't know why.

Query:

```
private static final String ADD_DOCUMENTS =
      "select * from table(Test.test_clob(in_document_clob => :cblob))";
```

Calling the query:

```
public void addDocuments(InputStream data, String name) throws IOException, SQLException {

    byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(data);

    SqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("cblob",
            new SqlLobValue(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray), byteArray.length, new DefaultLobHandler()), OracleTypes.CLOB);

    final List<SomeResponse> query = this.template.query(ADD_DOCUMENTS, paramSource, new SomeResponseMapper(true));
   
  }
```

I know so far, it works with strings as input, but not with clob's.

I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 32768 out of bounds for length 32768
>
> at oracle.sql.CharacterSet.convertJavaCharsToAL32UTF8Bytes(CharacterSet.java:1895)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.javaCharsToCHARBytes(DBConversion.java:832)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.javaCharsToCHARBytes(DBConversion.java:766)

When I try to call SqlLobValue without length param, I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Content type [[B] not supported for CLOB columns
>
> at org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.SqlLobValue.setTypeValue(SqlLobValue.java:204)
> at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(Statement CreatorUtils.java:292)

Many thanks for your help.

I tried to call when i try to call SqlLobValue without length param.

Comment: If you have any suggestions to improve my question, please let me know

Comment: PL/SQL (like your streaming function `test_clob`) has a size limit of 32K on CLOB variables.

Comment: @pmdba you're right, successfully tested with a smaller PDF, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @pmdba mentioned my Problem was the size limitation. Clob limit with streaming function are 32kb resolves to this error.

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 32768 out of bounds for length 32768

at oracle.sql.CharacterSet.convertJavaCharsToAL32UTF8Bytes(CharacterSet.java:1895)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.javaCharsToCHARBytes(DBConversion.java:832)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.javaCharsToCHARBytes(DBConversion.java:766)